# "org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Invalid message supplied" while sending email notification using ACS commons email service

Tags: aem

i'm trying to send email notification using ACS commons email service in a workflow and i'm getting below Error-

```
*ERROR* [JobHandler: /var/workflow/instances/server0/2020-04-17_3/workflow_59:/content/path/to/page] com.adobe.acs.commons.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl Error sending email to [ user@mail.com ]
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Invalid message supplied
    at org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail.setMsg(HtmlEmail.java:177) [org.apache.commons.email:1.5.0]
    at com.day.cq.commons.mail.MailTemplate.getEmail(MailTemplate.java:181) [com.day.cq.cq-commons:5.12.16]
    at com.adobe.acs.commons.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl.getEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:234) [com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle:4.3.0]
    at com.adobe.acs.commons.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl.sendEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:152) [com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle:4.3.0]
    at com.adobe.acs.commons.email.impl.EmailServiceImpl.sendEmail(EmailServiceImpl.java:125) [com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle:4.3.0]
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.advance.DynamicParticipantNodeHandler.getParticipant(DynamicParticipantNodeHandler.java:206) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.advance.ParticipantNodeHandler.doTransition(ParticipantNodeHandler.java:185) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.advance.ParticipantNodeHandler.doTransition(ParticipantNodeHandler.java:134) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.advance.OrSplitNodeHandler.doTransition(OrSplitNodeHandler.java:126) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.advance.AdvanceUtil.transitionFrom(AdvanceUtil.java:126) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.WorkflowSessionImpl.completeInternal(WorkflowSessionImpl.java:1050) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.WorkflowSessionImpl.complete(WorkflowSessionImpl.java:1020) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at <redacted>
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:195) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:260) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0002]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsumerManager.java:502) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:293) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:60) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:229) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

i have followed https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/e-mail/email-api/index.html

attaching html i have used in my template(i also tried with .txt file with normal text) -

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      -----------------------------------------<br/>
      Time :  ${time} <br/>
      Step : Approve Content <br/>
      Approver : userName <br/>
      Workflow :  wftitle<br/>
      -----------------------------------------<br/><br/>
      wftitle  workflow has been assigned to you. Please review the content: <a href=' url'>                            payloadTitle </a><br/><br/>----------------------------------------<br/>
      View the overview in your  <a href='test'>AEM Inbox</a><br/>
      -----------------------------------------<br/> This is an automatically generated message. Please do        not reply.
   </body>
</html>
```

please let me know what i'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the HTML message (please remove confidential information). According to the error message there is something wrong with the message. Otherwise, SO will have a hard time solving your issue.

Comment: @Jens - i have attached html that i used in email template ,  please take a look.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the email headers: _ From_, _Subject_ followed by an empty line. Make also sure that the template has the file ending ".html" as described in the documentation. Make sure to carefully read the documentation you linked.

Comment: @Jens- you are correct, after adding 'from:..' it started working. Initially i thought the 'from:' address would be taken from config.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Wonderful. Please add this as a separate answer to your question. This is allowed but important. This way it is immediately clear, that your question has an answer and what it is.

Comment: @Jens - sure, added you comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from @Jens-

Looks like you are missing the email headers: _ From_, Subject followed by an empty line. Make also sure that the template has the file ending ".html" as described in the documentation. Make sure to carefully read the documentation you linked